# Surface Area for Surface Integral, question on form

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

**How does $\left\|{\partial \mathbf{r} \over \partial x} \times {\partial \mathbf{r} \over \partial y}\right\| dx dy$ equal the patch of area for the surface integral?**

Wiki defines surface Area as:
$$
A = \iint_S \,\mathrm dS
= \iint_T \left\|{\partial \mathbf{r} \over \partial x} \times {\partial \mathbf{r} \over \partial y}\right\| \mathrm dx\, \mathrm dy
$$
where $\mathbf r : \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3, \mathbf r(x,y) = (x, y, f(x,y))$

I'm confused with the area form.  It's my understanding $\left\|{\partial \mathbf{r} \over \partial x} \times {\partial \mathbf{r} \over \partial y}\right\| = sin\theta ||{\partial \mathbf{r} \over \partial x}|| ||{\partial \mathbf{r} \over \partial y}|| = dA$ with the normal vector being the magnitude of the area,  but this contradicts the above.

Comment: given vectors $u,v, \|u\times v\| = \|u\|\|v\|\sin\theta =$ the area of the parellogram formed by $O, u,v, u+v.$  The surface area formula then finds the the area of $S$ over a little rectangle in the $xy$ plane that is $dx$ by $dy$ in area and then sums all such areas.

Comment: Do you mean $O + u, O + v, O + u + v$?  Why is the area of the parallelogram and $dx dy$ multiplied?  It seems two areas are multiplied.  Also $dx dy$ alone doesn't represent the area of the surface because the surface could non-parallel to that plane.

Answer (score 1):

If we mark out a little rectangle dx by dy in the xy plane, it corresponds to a parallelogram on the surface.

[image]

I didn't represent the entire surface just the portion immediately above my rectangle in the plane.

The area of this red parallelogram is $\|\frac {\partial r}{\partial x} \times \frac {\partial r}{\partial y}\|\ dx\ dy = \sqrt { (-\frac {\partial f}{\partial x})^2 + (-\frac {\partial f}{\partial y})^2 + 1}\ dx\ dy$

Why is it "dx dy multiplied"?

The $\|\frac {\partial r}{\partial x} \times \frac {\partial r}{\partial y}\|$ factor represents the degree that the the area on the surface is greater than the area below it in the plane.  The total area is this scaling factor times the area in the plane.

Comment: Helpful. I'm still trying to understand more about the degree of area and the scaling of the magnitude of cross product.  I seem to understand the trivial case of the red parallelogram being *parallel to* the $x,y$ plane and $dx dy$ rectangle, which  results in a scaling factor of 1, giving the area of $dx dy$.  I'm a bit lost with the case pictured here.  Appreciate your guidance

Comment: you can also think about the degree of scaling as the secant of the angle between the vector normal to the surface and vertical.